# Issue with the lookback for the last Bull or Bear Candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create a simple bit of code where you can lookback a certain amount of candles and find the last Bull or Bear candle but I seem to have completely missed something as when I add to the chart I am getting a **Negative Index Study Error** the idea is that when I work this out can then use to say where the last opposite candle is and when it gets broken to give a "Signal" which I will use in other code.

I expect I'm being blind to what I have missed.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Candle Lookback')

int lookback = input.int(title='Lookback', defval=10, minval=1)

int bearCount = 0
int bullCount = 0
int lastBearCandle = 0
int lastBullCandle = 0


int previousCandle = 2
for i = bar_index - lookback + 1 to bar_index by 1
    if previousCandle == 1 and close[i] < open[i]
        bearCount += 1
        bearCount
    else if previousCandle == 0 and close[i] >= open[i]
        bullCount += 1
        if bearCount > 0
            lastBearCandle := i
            lastBearCandle
        if bullCount > 0
            lastBullCandle := i
            lastBullCandle
    previousCandle := close[i] < open[i] ? 1 : 0
    previousCandle

bearback = lastBearCandle < lookback
bullback = lastBullCandle < lookback

plot(lastBearCandle, 'Last Bear Candle', color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=1)

plot(lastBullCandle, 'Last Bull Candle', color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=1)`
```

The error was actually happening on the plot which I resolved but still the issue is somewhere else

Comment: `close[i]` with i = bar_index is close[i bars ago], so it is too far from current bar_index. You probably should start with `i = 0` in a loop, i,e `for i = 0 to lookback` instead of `for i = bar_index - lookback + 1 to bar_index by 1
`